# How can I add a column to a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to add an extra column to the below pivot table. The new column should show the inactivity ratio (inactive / (inactive + active)).

I thought about using `.apply`, however, I don't know how to get the data; `pivot_table.count['active']` does not give me the data of all the active ones.

Can someone help me how I can to this?

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(valuable, values='partyPartnerId', 
                                index=['countryOfOrigin'], 
                                columns=['activity'], 
                                aggfunc=['count'],
                                fill_value=0)
```

```
activity          count
countryOfOrigin   active    inactive
AT                1         0
BE                1385      338
CZ                2         0
DE                61        6
DK                1         0
```

[image]

Comment: What is `valuable`? I guess it would help others if you provide a [mre] of creating the original data before you pivot. It doesn't have to be your full data, just a small enough example (like the image) to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by *@mozway*, you can avoid ending up with a *MultiIndex* columns by passing `aggfunc='count'` rather than `aggfunc=['count']`. Right after that, you can either [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) the ratio or use a classical new-column's [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) :

```
pivot_table = (
    pd.pivot_table(valuable,
        values='partyPartnerId', 
        index='countryOfOrigin',
        columns='activity',
        aggfunc='count', # use a string
        fill_value=0   
    ).eval('ratio = inactive / (inactive + active)')
)

# a variant chain woud be `.assign(ratio = lambda x: x['inactive'].div(x.sum(axis=1)))`
```

Output :

```
print(out)

activity         active  inactive  ratio
countryOfOrigin                         
AT                    1         0 0.0000
BE                 1385       338 0.1962
CZ                    2         0 0.0000
DE                   61         6 0.0896
DK                    1         0 0.0000
```

Used input :

```
vals = [[1, 0], [1385, 338], [2, 0], [61, 6], [1, 0]]
idxx = pd.Index(["AT", "BE", "CZ", "DE", "DK"], name="countryOfOrigin")
cols = pd.Index([("count", "active"), ("count", "inactive")], name=(None, "activity"))

pivot_table = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=idxx, columns=cols).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi mozway, [*erratum*]: The code in the OP shows `aggfunc=['count']`, I think that's the reason of the *MultiIndex* header. So, normally, we can avoid dropping the top-level (*that is* `count`) by passing a string rather than a list to the `aggfunc` parameter. Isn't that right? If so, I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: Yes sorry that's the issue. I forgot to double check ;)

Comment: No worries, I was misled by the `values` parameter at first but now it all makes sense. Thank you ;)

Comment: `index` and `columns` also probably don't need a list

Comment: I've made an update to address that. Now, I understand that there are two types of behaviors (*parameters*) when dealing with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), `values`/`aggfunc` and `index/columns` based on the type passed, whether it's a string or a list.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- "**pivot_table**" return a "**DataFrame**"

> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

- So you can add columns after doing the "**pivot**", like:

> pivot_table["inactive_ratio"] = pivot_table["inactive"] / (pivot_table["inactive"] + pivot_table["active"])
> print(pivot_table)